# Python Wrapper for Dynamic SQL

Tags: python, object-oriented, sql, pandas

```
# Stack Overflow 

'''
Goal: pull back all tables in a database where column name 'Audit Report' == 'complete'
Why is this a script: There are over 1000 tables in the database with the same structure
                        this script will automate checking which reports have a 'complete'
                         under the column name 'Audit Report'
This script will:
    1) pull down all of the tables in a database
    2) pull down all of the column names per table
    3) create a dataframe 
    4) filter to all tables that contain a column name 
    5) run a dynamic sql query based on filtered df
    6) print out tablenames
'''

# import modules 
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import time

# connect to database
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=111.11.111.11;'    # servername
                      'Database=databasename;'    # database name
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')


# Initialize the list to populate
listoftables = []
columnnames = []

# Step 1
# using the connection string 
# appending each table name to 'listoftables'
# this step will give us all of the database tables
cursor = conn.cursor()
for row in cursor.tables():
    listoftables.append(row.table_name)

# Step 2
# using all of the tables, we now want all of the column names
for x in listoftables:
    tempcolnames = []
    # for each table, get all of the column names
    for row in cursor.columns(table = x):
        tempcolnames.append(row.column_name)
    columnnames.append(tempcolnames)

# Step 3
# make a dataframe of the two lists
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'TableName': listoftables,
     'col_names'  : columnnames
    })

# Step 4
# filter to tables that are have 'Audit_Report' as a column name
df['status'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if 'Audit_Report' in x['col_names'] else 0, axis =1 )
# auditreports will return a dataframe with all tables that have 'Audit_Report' as a column name
auditreports = df[df['status'] == 1]


# start time to get an idea for how long the query runs
start_time = time.time()
# this is the 'shell' of the save location
merged=pd.DataFrame()


# Step 5
# this is the iterative sql loop we are going to run
for table in auditreports['TableName']:
    df = pd.read_sql_query('''
        select 
            *
        from 
            [dbo].[{}] 
        where 
            Audit_Report = 'Complete' 

        '''.format(table, username), conn)

    # checking if the query pulled down any data
    if len(df) > 0:
        df['TableName'] = table
        merged=pd.concat([merged,df], sort=False)
        # if it does have data we store it in 'merged' if it does not, the 'else' is implied as 'do nothing'
        # we dont need to say, else if all was want to do is 'do nothing'

    # waiting a tenth of a second to keep from overloading server or computer
    time.sleep(.1)

# how long the query took to run
minutes = (time.time() - start_time)/60
print('query took: ' + str(minutes) + ' minutes')

# Step 6
# print all reports that have been audited
merged
```

**Concerns:** Are my comments understandable?

**Potential #TODO:** this is considered a *Script*, how can I take this script and make it more flexible and create a method or Class that I can throw some kwargs and make it more program-like. What part of the script would be the easiest to turn into a method?